# Regex help: My regex pattern will match invalid strings

Tags: c#, regex, match, regex-group

The text string I want to validate consists of what I call "segments". A single segment might look like this:

```
 [A-Z,S,3]
```

So far I managed to build this regex pattern

```
(?:\[(?<segment>[^,\]\[}' ]+?,[S|D],\d{1})\])+?
```

it works but it will return matches even though the whole text string contains invalid text. I guess I need to use `^` and `$` somewhere in my pattern but I can't figure out how!?

I would like my pattern to produce the following results:

- `[A-Z,S,3][A-Za-z0-9åäöÅÄÖ,D,4]` **OK(two segments)**
- `[A-Z,S,3]aaaa[A-Za-z0-9åäöÅÄÖ,D,4]` **No match**
- `crap[A-Z,S,3][A-Za-z0-9åäöÅÄÖ,D,4]` **No match**
- `[A-Z,S,3][]` **No match**
- `[A-Z,S,3][klm,D,4][0-9,S,1]` **OK(three segments)**

Comment: C# (latest .Net 3.5). I also would like to extract the "segments" if I get a successfull match (if possible). Perhaps I need to have a second pattern to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ^ to anchor the start and $ to anchor the end.  E.g.: `^(abc)*$`, this matches zero or more repetitions of the group ("abc" in this example) and that must start at the start of the input string and end at the end of it.

`^(?:[(?[^,][}' ]+?,[S|D],\d{1})])+$`—using an ungreedy `+?` doesn't matter, as you require it to match until the end anyway.  However, your regex has a few issues.

`^(?:\[[^,]+,[SD],\d\])+$`—seems more like what you want.

- I couldn't decipher what you meant by the first part, so my regex is more general than required, `[^,]+,` will match any sequence of non-commas followed by a comma, and in fact you should probably add `]` to this negated character class.
- `[S|D]` is a character class of *three* characters, as `|` doesn't mean alternation here (`(S|D)` would mean the same as `[SD]` though).
- `{1}` is the default for any atom, you don't need to specify it.

---

[Pseudocode](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) (run it at [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/)):

```
import re
def find_segments(input_string):
  results = []
  regex = re.compile(r"\[([^],]+),([SD]),(\d)\]")
  start = 0
  while True:
    m = regex.match(input_string, start)
    if not m: # no match
      return None # whole string didn't match, do another action as appropriate
    results.append(m.group(1, 2, 3))
    start = m.end(0)
    if start == len(input_string):
      break
  return results

print find_segments("[A-Z,S,3][klm,D,4][0-9,S,1]")
# output:
#[('A-Z', 'S', '3'), ('klm', 'D', '4'), ('0-9', 'S', '1')]
```

The big difference here is the expression matches only the complete `[...]` part, but it is applied in succession, so they must start again where the last ends (or end at the end of the string).

Comment: Thanks! Great answer to my question. The thing is I would also like to extract the "segments". Either in a match collection or in groups. If you look at my original pattern you see that I first have a non-capturing group, then a capturing group "extracting" the "segment". Is it possible to incorporate that into your pattern?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same way, add the capturing group around what you're interested in.  However, you'll likely need to call your regex library with a different function in order to capture all of them, instead of just the first or last, as the capturing group is then instead a repetition.  I'll update with an example.

Comment: +1: That's a nice way to solve it in Python. It saves having two almost identical regexps, and the performance hit of matching on the same string twice. But does .NET's Regex have an option to say where the match should start like Python or will this require copying strings, nullifying the performance advantage?

Comment: "is then inside* a repetition."  (You're entering regex-engine-specific territory.)

Comment: Mark: beats me---had this question been marked C# specific from the start I'd likely have refrained (but you seem to have that part covered well anyway).  Picking up where another regex stops is essential at times---you can apply a completely different expression, or try out various ones, at that point.

Comment: Thanks all of you! You really put a lot of effort into helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
/^(\[[^],]+,[SD],\d\])+$/
```

Here is an example of how you could use this regular expression in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] tests = {
            "[A-Z,S,3][A-Za-z0-9,D,4]",
            "[A-Z,S,3]aaaa[A-Za-z0-9,D,4]",
            "crap[A-Z,S,3][A-Za-z0-9,D,4]",
            "[A-Z,S,3][]",
            "[A-Z,S,3][klm,D,4][0-9,S,1]"
        };

        string segmentRegex = @"\[([^],]+,[SD],\d)\]";
        string lineRegex = "^(" + segmentRegex + ")+$";

        foreach (string test in tests)
        {
            bool isMatch = Regex.Match(test, lineRegex).Success;
            if (isMatch)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successful match: " + test);
                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(test, segmentRegex))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Successful match: [A-Z,S,3][A-Za-z0-9,D,4]
A-Z,S,3
A-Za-z0-9,D,4
Successful match: [A-Z,S,3][klm,D,4][0-9,S,1]
A-Z,S,3
klm,D,4
0-9,S,1
```